# How to reduce a rounded div size based on parent size?

Tags: html, css

I have several round buttons inline wrapped by a parent called container.
The container does not have a fixed size. It will take up the entire width of the screen.

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: black;
}
.round {
  border-radius: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin-right: 2%;
  margin-left: 2%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <button class="round"></button>
  <button class="round"></button>
  <button class="round"></button>
</div>
```

The round button should have a **maximum width and height of 50px**.
But container reduces it's size and the round buttons doesnt have enough space to be displayed in one line, it should reduce the button size to fit everything in one line.

I know I can easily do this using media queries. But that can be messy. Is there a cleaner way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this might be what you're looking for. Set the `width` of the buttons to be a 3rd of the `width` of their parent with a `max-width` of 50px then add a floated pseudo element to the buttons with a bit of `padding` to keep the dimensions of the buttons square.

```css
*{box-sizing:border-box;border:0;margin:0;padding:0;}
div{
    padding:10px 0;
    text-align:center;
    width:100%;
}
button{
    background:#000;
    border-radius:50%;
    display:inline-block;
    margin:0 2%;
    width:calc(88% / 3);
    max-width:50px;
}
button:before{
    content:"";
    float:left;
    padding:50% 0;
}
```

```html
<div><button></button><button></button><button></button></div>
```

Comment: Hi. How do I set the height? On my app for some reason if I don't set a height (which should be equal to the width), the button looks like an oval. Also what if the buttons have margins as well? Ex; margin-left: 2%; margin-right: 2%

Comment: The pseudo element takes care of the height, allowing it to scale relative to the width. I've update my answer to accommodate margins - all you do is subtract the total of all the margins from the 100% width you're dividing by 3.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: black;
}
.round {
  border: medium none;
  border-radius: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin-right: 2%;
  margin-left: 2%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <button class="round"></button>
  <button class="round"></button>
  <button class="round"></button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The button element seems to have a default `padding:1px 6px;`. You can try setting the `padding:0;` in `.round` class. This will make the button size 46*46.

Since there is a border radius it occupies 2px*2px. If you set the `border:none;` it will make the button size 50*50